# convenient and precise calculation of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^b(n+m)^b}$

Tags: calculus, summation, special-functions

I would like to sum the following $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^b(n+m)^b}$$
for values of $b$ for which the sum exists. The problem is that truncating the sum does not work that good, and needs in general large number of terms specially when $b$ is close to non-summability areas. I then tried to rewrite the sum into some function for which we might have convenient and precise ways to calculate them.  Unfortunately have not been successful. I appreciate any ideas. Many thanks!

Comment: If $b$ is an integer, you may compute such series through partial fraction decomposition and the functions $\psi,\psi',\psi'',\ldots$ where $\psi(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\log\Gamma(x)$.

Comment: That's the problem. $b $ is not an integer.

Comment: The apply the inverse Laplace transform to convert your series into an integral.

Comment: That sounds interesting I will try. Thank you :-)

Comment: In the critical case $b\approx\frac{1}{2}$, you will see that the behaviour of your series depends on the behaviour of a Bessel $I$ function.

Comment: The thing is observing the link to bessel functions I thought there might be some functions still related that I don't know. But I understand the direction of your suggestion.

Comment: I took the liberty of putting the formula in the title, which (I think) makes the question a little easier to browse. You can revert it if it is not desired. But you might want to proofread the rest of the question as well to make it easier to read.

Comment: @DavidK this is great help. Thank you very much. I made some edits, sorry for the bad text.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Jack, first Happy Holidays!  As far as the first comment, suppose $b=k\in \mathbb{N}$.  I don't see a direct connection between the derivatives of the digamma function, $$\psi^{(k)}(m)=(-1)^{k+1}\,k!\,\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+m)^{k+1}} \tag 1$$and the function of interest herein, $$f_k(m)=\frac{1}{m^k}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+m}\right)^k \tag 2$$There seems to be a lot of work if we can make use of $(1)$ to express $(2)$.  If $b$ in not an integer, I don't see how application of the inverse Laplace transform converts the sum to an integral.

Comment: @Dr.MV: if you write $\frac{1}{n(n+m)}$ as $\frac{1}{m}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+m}\right)$, then consider the $b$-th power, you easily get terms manageable through partial fraction decomposition / the inverse Laplace transform / derivatives of the digamma function. Happy holidays to you too!

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Jack, as embedded in my comment, the $k$'th power, $\left(\frac1n - \frac{1}{n+m}\right)^k$ involve terms $\frac{1}{n^\ell}\frac{1}{(n+m)^{k-\ell}}$ for $\ell = 0 , \dots, k$.  Then, how does one proceed manageably?

Comment: @Dr.MV: to state it clearly, $$\frac{1}{n^b(n+m)^b}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma(b)}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-ns}e^{-ms/2}(m/s)^{1/2-b} I_{b-1/2}(ms/2)\,ds. $$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Jack, thanks for this.  Did you derive this expression or is this a "look up" in a treatise such as Gradshteyn?  It's not obvious to me how one starts with the LHS and arrives at the RHS integral representation.  Finally, given this relationship, the rest is easy.  In summing the LHS for $b>1/2$, we can justify easily interchanging the integral and the series (e.g., exploit uniform convergence for $b\ge b^{*} >1/2$) and sum the geometric series.

Comment: @Dr.MV: kind of both. I started computing the inverse Laplace transform by hand, got it wrong a couple of times, convinced myself it has to involve the Bessel I function, invoked greater gods for a confirmation :D

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio What are you viewing as the transform variable for $\frac{1}{n^b\,(n+m)^b}$?

Comment: @Dr.MV: $n$, in order to convert the series into $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sum_{n\geq 1}e^{-ns}\omega(s)\,ds.$

Comment: So, you attempted to evaluate $$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\sigma - i\infty }^{\sigma + i\infty} \left(\frac{1}{t^b(t+m)^b}\right)\,e^{st}\,dt?$$

Comment: If you use a Mellin transform with respect to $m$ you can get the original sum $S(b,m)$
$$
S(b,m)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma + i\infty} \frac{\Gamma(b-s)\Gamma(s)\zeta(2b-s)}{\Gamma(b)m^s} \; ds
$$