Closed form of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s(n+c)^s}$ where $c,s$ are positive integers
Is there a simple closed form representation of the following sum
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s(n+c)^s},
$$
where $s, c$ are positive integers, and $s>1$?
Clearly, this converges since:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s(n+c)^s} < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s} = \zeta(s).
$$
Mathematica is able to numerically compute the answers when inputting some specific values of $s, c$, so I was wondering if there was an analytic way (or numerical shorthand) of determining the value of the sum. I would also greatly appreciate any resources which discuss such sums.
If such a closed form exists, I was also wondering if sums such as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s(n+c)^s(n+d)^s}$ and those with more terms in the denominator have similar closed forms.

Related - https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2059956/1157207

The sum appears to be expressible as
$$\frac{(-1)^{s+1}}{2}X_c(s)+(-1)^s\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac s2\right\rfloor}\frac{\binom{2s-2k-1}{s-1}}{c^{2s-2k}}\zeta(2k),$$
for some function $X_c(s)$. I'm not able to completely determine a nice way to express $X_c(s)$, but computing it for the first few $c$ gives:
\begin{align*}
X_1&=0\\
X_2&=1\\
X_3&=\frac{2}{2^s}\\
X_4&=\frac{2}{3^s}+\frac{1}{4^s}\\
X_5&=\frac{2}{4^s}+\frac{2}{6^s}
\end{align*}
The first few terms of $X_6$ are $\frac{137}{180}$, $\frac{8009}{648000}$, and $\frac{496373}{23328000}$. The denominators are all half a power of $360$, but as of now I'm unable to find $X_6$ much less a general way to express $X_c$.

Your summand can be expanded explicitly as a partial fraction in $n$:
$$\frac 1{n^s(n+c)^s}=(-1)^s\sum_{i=1}^s\binom{2s-i-1}{s-1}c^{i-2s}\left(\frac{1}{(n+c)^i}+\frac{(-1)^i}{n^i}\right).$$
This is, for instance, a special case of an identity whose history is discussed in a series of papers by Koornwinder and Schlosser:
https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.2125
https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.6362
https://arxiv.org/abs/2304.10003
Summing over $n$, we note that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{(n+c)^i}+\frac{(-1)^i}{n^i}\right)=-\sum_{n=1}^c \frac 1{n^i}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1+(-1)^i}{n^i}.$$
The second term only appears when $i$ is even. Replacing $i$ by $2i$ in the corresponding terms gives
\begin{multline*}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac 1{n^s(n+c)^s}
=(-1)^{s+1}\sum_{i=1}^s\sum_{n=1}^c\binom{2s-i-1}{s-1}\frac{c^{i-2s}}{n^i}\\
+2(-1)^s\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor s/2\rfloor}\binom{2s-2i-1}{s-1}c^{2i-2s}\zeta(2i).\end{multline*}
